# Question about line-of-sight on a flat earth

Tags: earth

If the Earth were flat - could you (on a crystal clear day) see the Himalayas from the UK? (Assuming there were no obstructions in between) And secondly - would the view into space be any different?

Comment: "Flat Earth" and "Space exploration" are as far apart as you can get.  Space exploration is about what is really there.

Comment: True, but there are some very smart people here and IMO the question is (very) loosely related to space.

Comment: **The question is not about the flat earth "theory"** - it is a hyphothetical question about the transparency of the athmosphere and it should be viewed so. I suggest a reopen.

Comment: Btw, the answer is probably no - as far I know, the opaqueness of the athmosphere makes things un-visible from $\approx$ 400 km, at least this is the record where free eye can see. We face rarely this problem, because the normalized thickness of the athmosphere is only $\approx$ 5km.

Comment: @peterh even if it is a "a hyphothetical question about the transparency of the athmosphere" it's still off topic.